# SSIS :[Pivot [85]] Error: Duplicate pivot key value

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, pivot, transformation

[image: REQUIREMENT]

I am using PIVOT transformation in SSIS to achieve the above.(source Excel)
its showing duplicate pivot key value error.
Tried the below options
1.sort transformation before pivot on yearmonth,area,product,model,customer
2.changed pivot key value to 1 for yearmonth,area,product,model,customer colums

Can some one one please guide me on this ...

Answer (score 1):

One way around this is to use Aggregate task to group them together. This will ensure that there is 1 row for each distinct value.

[image]

Comment: @kelothk can I see your data flow?